# Emulating a keystroke using ARMv8 assembly and Uinput

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi3, gpio, wiringpi, armv8

Update 07/23/2018:

I have C-code with uinput implemented as follows:

```
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
void emit(int fd, int type, int code, int val)
{
   struct input_event ie;

   ie.type = type;
   ie.code = code;
   ie.value = val;
   /* timestamp values below are ignored */
   ie.time.tv_sec = 0;
   ie.time.tv_usec = 0;

   write(fd, &ie, sizeof(ie));
}

int main(void)
{
   struct uinput_setup usetup;

   int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);


   /*
    * The ioctls below will enable the device that is about to be
    * created, to pass key events, in this case the space key.
    */
   ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
   ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_W);

   memset(&usetup, 0, sizeof(usetup));
   usetup.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
   usetup.id.vendor = 0x1234; /* sample vendor */
   usetup.id.product = 0x5678; /* sample product */
   strcpy(usetup.name, "Example device");

   ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_SETUP, &usetup);
   ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);

   /*
    * On UI_DEV_CREATE the kernel will create the device node for this
    * device. We are inserting a pause here so that userspace has time
    * to detect, initialize the new device, and can start listening to
    * the event, otherwise it will not notice the event we are about
    * to send. This pause is only needed in our example code!
    */
   sleep(1);
   while(1){
   /* Key press, report the event, send key release, and report again */
   emit(fd, EV_KEY, KEY_W, 1);

    }
   /*
    * Give userspace some time to read the events before we destroy the
    * device with UI_DEV_DESTOY.
    */
   sleep(1);

   ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
   close(fd);

   return 0;
}
```

But there seems to be no output

---

Old Post 07/22/2018
I have been working on this project for a bit and have found help here in fixing some of my mistakes.

I have working ARM assembly code that takes button input from my raspberry pi 3's GPIO and I need one final thing to finally put this to rest once and for all.

I need to find some way to make the system think that a key was pressed with the button so a game can interpret the input as a keystroke in the game code. Or better yet just have a simple screen where I can move around a pixel on the screen. I'm finding it difficult to find help in the ARM language for this.

My code is as follows:

```
//data Section

         .data
         .align    4
Intro:   .asciz    "Raspberry Pi - Blinking led test inassembly\n"
ErrMsg:  .asciz    "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"
TestMsg: .asciz    "Test stuff\n"
Up:      .asciz    "Up pressed"
Left:    .asciz    "Left Pressed"
Down:    .asciz    "Down Pressed"
Right:   .asciz    "Right pressed"
Pause:   .asciz    "Pause pressed"
Quit:    .asciz    "Quit pressed"
Pressed: .asciz    "button pressed"

// WiringPi pin values
pinUp:   .int      15
pinLeft: .int    3
pinDown: .int    0
pinRight:.int    7
pinPau:  .int    16
pinQu:   .int    2
i:       .int    10
Compr:   .int    1
INPUT    =       0

//Code section

    .text
    .global main
    .extern printf
    .extern scanf
    .extern wiringPiSetup
    .extern delay
    .extern digitalRead
    .extern pinMode

main:   push    {ip, lr}
// printf message
    ldr r0, =Intro
    bl  printf

//Check for setup error
    bl  wiringPiSetup
    mov r1,#-1
    cmp r0, r1
    bne init
    ldr r0, =ErrMsg
    bl  printf
    b   done
init:
    //Set all pins to input
    ldr r0, =pinUp
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    ldr r0, =pinLeft
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    ldr r0, =pinDown
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    ldr r0, =pinRight
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    ldr r0, =pinPau
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    ldr r0, =pinQu
    ldr r0, [r0]
    mov r1, #INPUT
    bl  pinMode

    b while 
while:

    //Digital Read
    ldr r0, =pinUp
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msg


    ldr r0, =pinLeft
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msgleft


    ldr r0, =pinDown
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msgdown

    ldr r0, =pinRight
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msgRight

    ldr r0, =pinPau
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msgpause

    ldr r0, =pinQu
    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl digitalRead
    cmp r0, #1
    beq msgquit

    b while         // Loop back

// Messages for input
msg:
    ldr r0, =Up
    bl printf
    b  while

msgleft:
    ldr r0, =Left
    bl printf
    b  while

msgRight:
    ldr r0, =Right
    bl printf
    b while
msgdown:
    ldr r0, =Down
    bl printf
    b while
msgpause:
    ldr r0, =Pause
    bl printf
    b while
msgquit:
    ldr r0, =Quit
    bl printf
    b while

done:   

    pop {ip,pc}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

To inject keypresses for all Linux programs you need to use the [uinput interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html).

Open `/dev/input/uinput` or `/dev/uinput`, configure it with ioctl calls, then write input event structures.

Comment: @ Timothy Baldwin I am completely new to this so i have no clue what to change or what a ioctl call does. I know it is Input output control but other wise i've got nothing.

Comment: Did you follow the link I provided to the documention? What did you not understand?

Comment: Okay i have a better understanding of what you said. I looked into the link and I'm trying to implement it now. I think the code I have should be pressing "w" continuously, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have a game running to test the input. Ill update the question with the new C-code